# Show missing rows with 0 values to maintain the order

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

I have a table with a Name column that its values are either 'A', 'B' or 'C'. They come in order ( A, B, C, A, B, C, ...) however, sometimes a Name might be missing (A, B,[missing C] A, B, C, ...). I want a query that gives me all of Names in order without any missing name. The Value for missing names must be 0.

PS: The table is in a Netezza database and it gets truncated and reloaded with fresh data each time by an SSIS package. What we know is that there is also an ID column with a value between 1 and 27. But the number of rows after each truncation and loading could be different. The table I want does not need the ID column, but if it had, it would be from 1 to 27, meaning that the 'table I want' must always have 27 rows.

[image]

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.  Do you have such a column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for your response. I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly. But I have no other column. These are what will to feed an application with, and the application needs to read the records in A, B, C order. If the order in not maintained it crashes. So, we need to have A, B, C, with 0 values if the value is missing.

Comment: In the table you have, how are you determining A=4 is paired with B = 1 and A=2.5 is paired with B=3? Do these values already exist in a database table with no other columns? Or are they coming from another source, like a text file?

Comment: @Ehz the table is a data set that is the result of some query and comes into my package in this form. I need to write it into an XML file, but the application that reads the XML needs to 'see' 0s whenever some value is missing. How do I determine that A=4 is paired with B=1 etc.? Just based on its order in the dataset, i.e. the fact that B=1 is right after A=4. Nothing more is here.

Comment: How is that order in the dataset determined?

Comment: If you are just querying without an order by clause, that may seem to have a consistent order based on ctid / insertion order, but it is not guaranteed

Comment: Show us the 'underlying query' that delivers that data into you package. That's where the extra rows can be added. BTW: What 'package' are we talking about???

Comment: @LarsGOlsen it is an SSIS package. I'll update the question soon with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend fixing this in the source SSIS package, but I think the following will work in Netazza (for versions that support the WITH command). Note that recursion is not used which I believe isn't support by Netazza.

If the WITH command isn't supported then some other source of a numeric seqeunce could be used (e.g. by row_number() )

setup:

```
CREATE TABLE TableHave
    (Name varchar(1), ID int, Value decimal(5,2))
;

INSERT INTO TableHave
    (Name, ID)
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('A', 4),
    ('A', 7),
    ('C', 21),
    ('B', 23),
    ('A', 25)
;

update TableHave set Value = id*1.12;
```

Query:

```
;WITH
Digits AS (
    SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
),
Tally AS (
    SELECT
           ones.digit
         + tens.digit * 10
         + hundreds.digit * 100
         -- + thousands.digit * 1000
         as num
    FROM Digits ones
    CROSS JOIN Digits tens
    CROSS JOIN Digits hundreds
    -- CROSS JOIN Digits thousands (keep adding more if needed)
)
select
       d.id
     , d.name
     , t.value
from (
    select 
           num + 1 as id
         , case when num % 3 = 1 then 'B'
                when num % 3 = 2 then 'C'
                else 'A'
           end Name
         , coalesce(t.value,0) value
    from Tally
    where num <= (select ((max(id)/3)*3)+2 from TableHave)
    ) d
left join TableHave t on d.id = t.id
order by d.id
```

result:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | A    | 1.12  |
|  2 | B    | 0     |
|  3 | C    | 0     |
|  4 | A    | 4.48  |
|  5 | B    | 0     |
|  6 | C    | 0     |
|  7 | A    | 7.84  |
|  8 | B    | 0     |
|  9 | C    | 0     |
| 10 | A    | 0     |
| 11 | B    | 0     |
| 12 | C    | 0     |
| 13 | A    | 0     |
| 14 | B    | 0     |
| 15 | C    | 0     |
| 16 | A    | 0     |
| 17 | B    | 0     |
| 18 | C    | 0     |
| 19 | A    | 0     |
| 20 | B    | 0     |
| 21 | C    | 23.52 |
| 22 | A    | 0     |
| 23 | B    | 25.76 |
| 24 | C    | 0     |
| 25 | A    | 28.00 |
| 26 | B    | 0     |
| 27 | C    | 0     |
+----+------+-------+
```

A running example (on SQL Server) is available here http://rextester.com/VXB89713

Comment: I like your code, also thanks for providing the code online.